# Непонятки с преобразованием типов - пример из книги Лафоре C++

Tags: c++

В книги Лафоре С++, приводится странный пример преобразования типов.

Насколько я знаю.. если мы кастуем int к float, то выделяется память для float и 7 преобразуется в 7.0.

В книги почему-то 7 преобразуется к 7.5. Это ошибка? Или старые версии компиляторов так делали?

Кто знает ответ - помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

[image: Пример из книги]

Comment: 7 в 7.5 - скорее всего ошибка художника, рисунок переделывавшего... Надо посмотреть оригинал.

Comment: Спасибо, @Harry, тоже думаю на глупость похоже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В оригинале книги иллюстрация выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что при переводе на русский бывает по-разному. Бывает, что пару сотен ошибок добавлено, если книга горит, и дали кому-то бегом, чтоб поскорее выпустить (например, первое издание "Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием С++" Страуструпа)... Бывает и наоборот - пара сотен ошибок в русском издании исправлено (например, "Компиляторы" Ахо, Лам, Сети и Ульмана).

Все очень сильно зависит от того, кто книгу делал. Так что как совет - смотреть не только (а часто и не столько) на автора переводной книги, сколько на то, кто именно книгу делал...

Comment: Четвертое издание и с ошибками:)

Comment: А, номер издания ни о чем не говорит...